# junits failing with easymock

Tags: junit, mocking, easymock

I am using EasyMock to write unit tests for my blackjack game.
But I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class com.blackjack.game.cards.Card` error.

Although, I feel I am doing it the right way.
Here is my testclass :

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.easymock.EasyMockRunner;
import org.easymock.EasyMockSupport;

@RunWith(EasyMockRunner.class)
public class handTest extends EasyMockSupport{
    private Hand hand;
    private Card seven, nine, ten, jack, ace;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception
    {
        seven = EasyMock.createNiceMock(Card.class);
        EasyMock.expect(seven.getValue()).andStubReturn(7);
        EasyMock.expect(seven.toString()).andStubReturn("seven value: 7");

    }

    @Test
    public void testTotalHandValueByAddingNumbers() {
        replayAll();
        hand.addCard(seven);

        assertEquals(27, hand.getTotal());


    }
}
```

I would be glad, if somebody could help me run this. It's been a while since I have written unit tests.

Edit: I have both of Objenesis and cglib in my classpath.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have the other libraries required for class mocking?

cglib (2.2) and Objenesis (1.2) must be in the classpath to perform class mocking

Comment: Yes. I am using both of those in my classpath.

Answer (score 0):

In all probability your class `com.blackjack.game.cards.Card` is final class

and `createNiceMock` or in that sense EasyMock cannot be used to mock the final classes.

You will need to use Powermock for this case, have a look at this resource for more inputs https://dzone.com/articles/mock-final-class#mock-final-class

Hope this helps!

Good luck!